# Resilience4j context propagator not able to propagte thread local values

Tags: java, spring, thread-local, resilience4j

I am trying to migrate my circuit breaker code from Hystrix to Resilience4j. The communication is between two applications out of which one is an artifact containing all the resilience 4j config in the java code itself and the second application which is a microservice uses it directly.

There's one RequestId which generates in the microservice and propagates to the artifact context where it gets printed in the logs. With Hystrix, it was working perfectly fine but ever since I moved to resilience, I am getting null for the request Id.

Below is my config for bulk head and context propagator :

```
ThreadPoolBulkheadConfig bulkheadConfig = ThreadPoolBulkheadConfig.custom()
            .maxThreadPoolSize(maxThreadPoolSize)
            .coreThreadPoolSize(coreThreadPoolSize)
            .queueCapacity(queueCapacity)
            .contextPropagator(new DummyContextPropagator())
            .build();

    // Bulk Head Registry
    ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry bulkheadRegistry = ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry.of(bulkheadConfig);

    // Create Bulk Head
    ThreadPoolBulkhead bulkhead = bulkheadRegistry.bulkhead(name, bulkheadConfig);
```

Dummy Context Propagator  :

```
public class  DummyContextPropagator implements ContextPropagator {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DummyContextPropagator.class);

@Override
public Supplier<Optional<Object>> retrieve() {
    return () -> (Optional<Object>) get();
}

@Override
public Consumer<Optional<Object>> copy() {
    return (t) -> t.ifPresent(e -> {
        clear();
        put(e);
    });
}

@Override
public Consumer<Optional<Object>> clear() {
    return (t) ->  DummyContextHolder.clear();
}

public static class  DummyContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();

    private  DummyContextHolder() {
    }

    public static void put(Object context) {
        if (threadLocal.get() != null) {
            clear();
        }
        threadLocal.set(context);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        if (threadLocal.get() != null) {
            threadLocal.set(null);
            threadLocal.remove();
        }
    }

    public static Optional<Object> get() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(threadLocal.get());
    }
}
}
```

However, nothing seems to work so that I can get the RequestId.

Am I doing everything right or is there another way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

i find my last answer may lead to some problems, when you use "dispatcherServlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);"

it may pollute your custom thread-pool`s threadlocalmap;

so here is my final resolve, and it only works at resilience4j;

```
@Resource
Resilience4jBulkheadProvider resilience4jBulkheadProvider;

@PostConstruct
public void concurrentThreadContextStrategy() {
    ThreadPoolBulkheadConfig threadPoolBulkheadConfig = ThreadPoolBulkheadConfig.custom().contextPropagator(new CustomInheritContextPropagator()).build();
    resilience4jBulkheadProvider.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4jBulkheadConfigurationBuilder()
            .bulkheadConfig(BulkheadConfig.ofDefaults()).threadPoolBulkheadConfig(threadPoolBulkheadConfig)
            .build());
}


private static class CustomInheritContextPropagator implements ContextPropagator<RequestAttributes> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<Optional<RequestAttributes>> retrieve() {
        //  give requestcontext to reference from threadlocal;
        //  this method call by web-container thread, such as tomcat, jetty,or undertow, depends on what you used;
        return () -> Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes());
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer<Optional<RequestAttributes>> copy() {
        // load requestcontex into real-call thread
        // this method call by resilience4j bulkhead thread;
        return requestAttributes -> requestAttributes.ifPresent(context -> {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer<Optional<RequestAttributes>> clear() {
        // clean requestcontext finally ;
        // this method call by resilience4j bulkhead thread;
        return requestAttributes -> RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to get params from threadlocal from parent-thread when you in sub-thread, in hystrix it use command-model to decorate callabletask

in resilience4j i think u can fix it like this:

```
@Resource
DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

@PostConstruct
public void changeThreadLocalModel() {
    dispatcherServlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem with springboot 2.5 et springboot cloud 2020.0.6
and I solved it with an implementation of **ContextPropagator**

```
public class SleuthPropagator implements ContextPropagator<TraceContext> {
    ThreadLocal<ScopedSpan> scopedSpanThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public Supplier<Optional<TraceContext>> retrieve() {
        return this::getCurrentcontext;
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer<Optional<TraceContext>> copy() {
        return c -> {
            if (!c.isPresent()) {
                return;
            }
            TraceContext traceContext = c.get();
            ScopedSpan resilience4jSpan = getTracer()
                    .map(t -> t.startScopedSpanWithParent("Resilience4j", traceContext))
                    .orElse(null);
            scopedSpanThreadLocal.set(resilience4jSpan);
        };
    }


    @Override
    public Consumer<Optional<TraceContext>> clear() {
        return t -> {
            try {
                ScopedSpan resilience4jSpan = scopedSpanThreadLocal.get();
                if (resilience4jSpan != null) {
                    resilience4jSpan.finish();
                }
            } finally {
                scopedSpanThreadLocal.remove();
            }
        };
    }

    private static Optional<Tracer> getTracer() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(Tracing.current())
                .map(Tracing::tracer);
    }

    private Optional<TraceContext> getCurrentcontext() {
        return getTracer()
                .map(Tracer::currentSpan)
                .map(Span::context);
    }
}
```

And use the propagator in adding this to your application.properties

```
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.instances.YOUR_BULKHEAD_CONFIG.context-propagators=com.your.package.SleuthPropagator
```